# Pandas recursive slicing to find min value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I do have python data frame as below. I am trying to slice the data frame where ever "slice" column value is 10 and then find the min of "low" column between 10 and previous non 0 value column

```
                   date      open      high       low     close  slice
0   2022-05-19 09:15:00  33461.00  33624.90  33403.20  33412.45      0
1   2022-05-19 09:20:00  33413.10  33450.65  33393.90  33429.10      0
2   2022-05-19 09:25:00  33433.20  33490.05  33421.95  33460.25      0
3   2022-05-19 09:30:00  33460.55  33509.40  33419.05  33489.80      0
4   2022-05-19 09:35:00  33492.20  33506.40  33450.30  33454.70     20
5   2022-05-19 09:40:00  33452.25  33452.95  33396.40  33436.15      0
6   2022-05-19 09:45:00  33434.30  33454.80  33401.35  33439.05      0
7   2022-05-19 09:50:00  33438.30  33482.85  33423.50  33477.30     10
8   2022-05-19 09:55:00  33480.60  33535.85  33462.40  33523.65     30
9   2022-05-19 10:00:00  33527.65  33527.65  33484.10  33521.40      0
10  2022-05-19 10:05:00  33519.35  33599.25  33505.95  33530.55      0
11  2022-05-19 10:10:00  33527.50  33544.20  33496.60  33538.65      0
12  2022-05-19 10:15:00  33540.15  33565.85  33522.75  33563.25      0
13  2022-05-19 10:20:00  33563.50  33582.45  33525.95  33539.25      0
14  2022-05-19 10:25:00  33537.25  33537.50  33511.80  33516.35     20
15  2022-05-19 10:30:00  33518.00  33561.80  33513.60  33528.55      0
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00  33527.80  33551.00  33527.55  33550.50     10
17  2022-05-19 10:40:00  33551.50  33573.60  33525.85  33537.45      0
18  2022-05-19 10:45:00  33534.80  33563.10  33510.75  33555.95      0
19  2022-05-19 10:50:00  33555.55  33573.45  33540.45  33541.00      0
20  2022-05-19 10:55:00  33545.40  33586.80  33542.75  33586.80     10
```

```
def buy_sell(data):
    Time = []
    SignalBuy = [] 
    BuySL = [] 
    BuyTgt = []  

    for i in range(len(data)):
                   if data["slice"][i] == 10:
                       Time.append(data["date"][i])
                       entry = data["open"][i]
                       sl = data["low"][i] - 10
                       SignalBuy.append(entry)
                       BuySL.append(sl)
                       BuyTgt.append(entry + (entry - sl) * 2)

    return pd.Series([Time, SignalBuy, BuyTgt, BuySL])

SignalDemand = pd.DataFrame()
SignalDemand["Time"], SignalDemand["Entry Price"], SignalDemand["Target"], SignalDemand["Stop Loss"]  = buy_sell(data)

print(SignalDemand.head())
```

This code gives me output as below.

```
                  Time  Entry Price    Target  Stop Loss
0  2022-05-19 09:50:00     33438.30  33487.90   33413.50
1  2022-05-19 10:35:00     33527.80  33548.30   33517.55
2  2022-05-19 10:55:00     33545.40  33570.70   33532.75
```

Expected output is

slice 1 - "Entry price" ( min of "open" or "close")  ie 33434.30, "Stop loss" ( min of "low" - 10 ) ie ( 33396.40 - 10 = ) 33386.40

```
                   date      open      high       low     close  slice
4   2022-05-19 09:35:00  33492.20  33506.40  33450.30  33454.70     20
5   2022-05-19 09:40:00  33452.25  33452.95  33396.40  33436.15      0
6   2022-05-19 09:45:00  33434.30  33454.80  33401.35  33439.05      0
7   2022-05-19 09:50:00  33438.30  33482.85  33423.50  33477.30     10
```

Slice 2 - "Entry price" ( min of "open" or "close")  ie 33516.35, "Stop loss" ( min of "low" - 10 ) ie ( 33511.80 - 10 = ) 33501.80

```
                   date      open      high       low     close  slice
14  2022-05-19 10:25:00  33537.25  33537.50  33511.80  33516.35     20
15  2022-05-19 10:30:00  33518.00  33561.80  33513.60  33528.55      0
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00  33527.80  33551.00  33527.55  33550.50     10
```

slice 3 - If previous value is same, i need to exclude the first row, ie row now 16 should be excluded.

"Entry price" ( min of "open" or "close")  ie 33534.80, "Stop loss" ( min of "low" - 10 ) ie ( 33510.75 - 10 = ) 33500.75

```
                   date      open      high       low     close  slice
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00  33527.80  33551.00  33527.55  33550.50     10

17  2022-05-19 10:40:00  33551.50  33573.60  33525.85  33537.45      0
18  2022-05-19 10:45:00  33534.80  33563.10  33510.75  33555.95      0
19  2022-05-19 10:50:00  33555.55  33573.45  33540.45  33541.00      0
20  2022-05-19 10:55:00  33545.40  33586.80  33542.75  33586.80     10
```

Final output should be

```
                  Time  Entry Price    Target  Stop Loss
0  2022-05-19 09:50:00     33434.30  33530.10   33386.40
1  2022-05-19 10:35:00     33516.35  33545.45   33501.80
2  2022-05-19 10:55:00     33534.80  33602.90   33500.75
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I noticed I made a number of mistakes after sitting down with this one and was kind of interested since I wanted to make my own trading bot one day so I took the time to fix them for ya.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

table = StringIO("""date    open    high    low close   slice
0   2022-05-19 09:15:00 33461.00    33624.90    33403.20    33412.45    0
1   2022-05-19 09:20:00 33413.10    33450.65    33393.90    33429.10    0
2   2022-05-19 09:25:00 33433.20    33490.05    33421.95    33460.25    0
3   2022-05-19 09:30:00 33460.55    33509.40    33419.05    33489.80    0
4   2022-05-19 09:35:00 33492.20    33506.40    33450.30    33454.70    20
5   2022-05-19 09:40:00 33452.25    33452.95    33396.40    33436.15    0
6   2022-05-19 09:45:00 33434.30    33454.80    33401.35    33439.05    0
7   2022-05-19 09:50:00 33438.30    33482.85    33423.50    33477.30    10
8   2022-05-19 09:55:00 33480.60    33535.85    33462.40    33523.65    30
9   2022-05-19 10:00:00 33527.65    33527.65    33484.10    33521.40    0
10  2022-05-19 10:05:00 33519.35    33599.25    33505.95    33530.55    0
11  2022-05-19 10:10:00 33527.50    33544.20    33496.60    33538.65    0
12  2022-05-19 10:15:00 33540.15    33565.85    33522.75    33563.25    0
13  2022-05-19 10:20:00 33563.50    33582.45    33525.95    33539.25    0
14  2022-05-19 10:25:00 33537.25    33537.50    33511.80    33516.35    20
15  2022-05-19 10:30:00 33518.00    33561.80    33513.60    33528.55    0
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00 33527.80    33551.00    33527.55    33550.50    10
17  2022-05-19 10:40:00 33551.50    33573.60    33525.85    33537.45    0
18  2022-05-19 10:45:00 33534.80    33563.10    33510.75    33555.95    0
19  2022-05-19 10:50:00 33555.55    33573.45    33540.45    33541.00    0
20  2022-05-19 10:55:00 33545.40    33586.80    33542.75    33586.80    10""")


data = pd.read_csv(table, sep='\t')

def formatRow(rows):
    tmp_list = []
    for i in rows.index:
        time = rows['date'][i]
        entry = rows['open'][i]
        sl = rows['low'][i] - 10
        target = entry + (entry - sl) * 2 
        tmp_list.append([time, entry, target, sl, i])
    return tmp_list 


data.columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'slice']
data['group_min'] = False

# Filtering data by slice value
df = data[data['slice'] > 0]
buysell_list = []
for i in range(len(df)): #
    print('Processing: ', i)
    if df.iloc[i]['slice'] == 10:
        group = group + 1
        if i != 0:
            start_index = df.iloc[i-1].name
            end_index = df.iloc[i].name

            while data.loc[start_index]['slice'] == 10:
                print('previous slice > 0 is a 10!')
                start_index = start_index + 1

            if start_index < end_index:    
                rows = data.loc[start_index:end_index]
                print('range {}-{}'.format(start_index, end_index))
                data.loc[rows.index, 'group'] = group
                min_row_index = rows['low'].idxmin()
                # In case there are two lows that are somehow equal
                min_rows = rows[rows['low'] == rows.loc[min_row_index]['low']]              
                data.loc[min_rows.index, 'group_min'] = True

                rows_formatted = formatRow(min_rows)
            else:
                print('Somehow slices are next to each other')
                rows_formatted = formatRow(df.iloc[i])
        else:
            print('First non zero is a 10')
            # This isn't complete, you would need to calc from the index here to index 0
            rows_formatted = formatRow(df.iloc[i])
        for row_f in rows_formatted:
            buysell_list.append(row_f)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(buysell_list, columns=['Time', 'Entry Price', 'Target', 'Stop Loss', 'Orig_Index'])
df2
```

Output

```
    Time    Entry Price Target  Stop Loss   Orig_Index
0   2022-05-19 09:40:00 33452.25    33583.95    33386.40    5
1   2022-05-19 10:25:00 33537.25    33608.15    33501.80    14
2   2022-05-19 10:45:00 33534.80    33602.90    33500.75    18
```

data.to_markdown()

Output

|  | date | open | high | low | close | slice | group_min | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-05-19 09:15:00 | 33461 | 33624.9 | 33403.2 | 33412.4 | 0 | False |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-19 09:20:00 | 33413.1 | 33450.7 | 33393.9 | 33429.1 | 0 | False |  |
| 2 | 2022-05-19 09:25:00 | 33433.2 | 33490.1 | 33421.9 | 33460.2 | 0 | False |  |
| 3 | 2022-05-19 09:30:00 | 33460.6 | 33509.4 | 33419.1 | 33489.8 | 0 | False |  |
| 4 | 2022-05-19 09:35:00 | 33492.2 | 33506.4 | 33450.3 | 33454.7 | 20 | False | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-05-19 09:40:00 | 33452.2 | 33452.9 | 33396.4 | 33436.2 | 0 | True | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-05-19 09:45:00 | 33434.3 | 33454.8 | 33401.3 | 33439.1 | 0 | False | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-05-19 09:50:00 | 33438.3 | 33482.8 | 33423.5 | 33477.3 | 10 | False | 1 |
| 8 | 2022-05-19 09:55:00 | 33480.6 | 33535.8 | 33462.4 | 33523.7 | 30 | False |  |
| 9 | 2022-05-19 10:00:00 | 33527.7 | 33527.7 | 33484.1 | 33521.4 | 0 | False |  |
| 10 | 2022-05-19 10:05:00 | 33519.3 | 33599.2 | 33505.9 | 33530.6 | 0 | False |  |
| 11 | 2022-05-19 10:10:00 | 33527.5 | 33544.2 | 33496.6 | 33538.7 | 0 | False |  |
| 12 | 2022-05-19 10:15:00 | 33540.2 | 33565.8 | 33522.8 | 33563.2 | 0 | False |  |
| 13 | 2022-05-19 10:20:00 | 33563.5 | 33582.4 | 33525.9 | 33539.2 | 0 | False |  |
| 14 | 2022-05-19 10:25:00 | 33537.2 | 33537.5 | 33511.8 | 33516.3 | 20 | True | 2 |
| 15 | 2022-05-19 10:30:00 | 33518 | 33561.8 | 33513.6 | 33528.6 | 0 | False | 2 |
| 16 | 2022-05-19 10:35:00 | 33527.8 | 33551 | 33527.6 | 33550.5 | 10 | False | 2 |
| 17 | 2022-05-19 10:40:00 | 33551.5 | 33573.6 | 33525.8 | 33537.4 | 0 | False | 3 |
| 18 | 2022-05-19 10:45:00 | 33534.8 | 33563.1 | 33510.8 | 33555.9 | 0 | True | 3 |
| 19 | 2022-05-19 10:50:00 | 33555.6 | 33573.4 | 33540.4 | 33541 | 0 | False | 3 |
| 20 | 2022-05-19 10:55:00 | 33545.4 | 33586.8 | 33542.8 | 33586.8 | 10 | False | 3 |

Comment: Given code is pretty much close to my requirement.  Only thing is I want to poll in reverse order and find the min values.
```
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00  33527.80  33551.00  33527.55  33550.50     10
17  2022-05-19 10:40:00  33551.50  33573.60  33525.85  33537.45      0
18  2022-05-19 10:45:00  33534.80  33563.10  33510.75  33555.95      0
19  2022-05-19 10:50:00  33555.55  33573.45  33540.45  33541.00      0
20  2022-05-19 10:55:00  33545.40  33586.80  33542.75  33586.80     10
```
start form index 20 and ignore index 16. Any non 0 value other than 10 should included in the calculation.

Comment: The code is checking the rows before the 10, just as a block and not just going 20, 19, 18 (just curious, why is that a requirement? Going line by line is much slower)

Comment: 3 Things.
1* I want to exclude previous row if its equals to  10 else include in calculation
ie,  if df.iloc[i]['slice'] == df.iloc[i-1]['slice']: Then exclude i-1 from further calculation.
2* Entry = min of ( open & close ) between the slices
3* SL = min ( low) between those slices

Comment: below code along with  initial sugstn
        start = df.iloc[i]['date']
        end = df.iloc[i-1]['date']
        if df.iloc[i-1]['slice'] == 10 or df.iloc[i-1]['slice'] == 30:       
            min_row = data[(data["date"] > end) & (data["date"] <= start)]
            time = df.iloc[i]['date']
            entry = min_row[['open', 'close']].min().min()
            sl = min_row['low'].min() - 10
            target = entry + (entry - sl) * 2
            row = pd.Series([time, entry, target, sl])
            df2 = df2.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            pass

Comment: The new code already reflects all those changes except the min for the open/close and the slice ==30.  The other logic you added is redundant as the new code I added looks at the index and checks if that previous slice not 0 is a 10 (just need to add to the while slice in [10, 30]

Comment: Really appreciated your help. The code which you shared helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure theres better ways to do this using vectorization, but the way you have it, you're not even polling the previous rows to compare it to the current value. There's multiple approaches to this problem.  This one just sets the min value found between the current non 0 and the next non 0.

```
data['slice_min'] = None
data['slice_min_index_ref'] = None

def get_mins(data):

    min = None
    index_ref = None
    for i in range(len(data)):
        low = data.iloc[i]['low']
        if min == None: # Just setting up the first low
            min = low
        else:
            if low < min:
                #print('new low {}'.format(low))
                min = low # Setting new low
                index_ref = i+1 # in case you want to refer to the index. +1 because you used range
        if data.iloc[i]['slice'] > 0: # start over 
            data.at[i+1, 'slice_min'] = min # Set the min value only one values where a slice isn't 0. 
            data.at[i+1, 'slice_min_index_ref'] = index_ref
            index_ref = i+1
            min = low
    return data


df = get_mins(data)

df_slices = df[df['slice'] == 10] ## Just select the rows with slice 10
df_slices
```

Output

```
        date    open    high    low         close       slice   slice_min   slice_min_index_ref
0                               
7   2022-05-19 09:50:00 33438.3 33482.85    33423.50    33477.3 10  33396.4     5
16  2022-05-19 10:35:00 33527.8 33551.00    33527.55    33550.5 10  33511.8     14
20  2022-05-19 10:55:00 33545.4 33586.80    33542.75    33586.8 10  33510.75    18
```